# while recording jmeter script "object reference not set to an object instance" error message is displaying

Tags: jmeter

Why this error shows up in jmeter.in my work flow I am trying to order food online , i entered date and time of delivery.when i run this script . the request containing date and time shows this error "object reference not set to an object instance".
Can anyone help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com! Show the code you're having trouble with, so you can get more specific advice. Learn more on how stackoverflow works by taking the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I am trying to figure out the same problem. The site I am running recorded test scripts against is a .aspx site with applets.